# JAX pytree for xarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray, jax

Is it possible to create a pytree (for JAX) based upon an `xarray.DataArray`?

The key issue seems to be that the `data` attribute of an `xarray.DataArray` is constructed as a `numpy.ndarray` view of the input array (such as `DeviceArray`)

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import xarray as xr

da = xr.DataArray(
    data=jnp.array([2.0,3.0]),
    dims=("var"),
    coords={"var": ["A","B"]},
)

>>> type(da.data)

    numpy.ndarray
```

Flattening/Unflattening the `DataArray` into a pytree is relatively straight-forward (all the attributes are aux except `data`), but I don't know how to retrieve the `DeviceArray`, or even assign to it (I can't use `at[.].set(.)` here).

The alternative approach of constructing a container class (with `DeviceArray` member) requires that all the relevant functionality of xarray be manually implemented. For a single feature, such as labelled indexing, this is possible but redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do what you want by registering the xarray type as a custom PyTree node following the examples in the [documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytrees.html#extending-pytrees).

For example, it might look like this:

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import tree_util
import xarray as xr

tree_util.register_pytree_node(
    xr.DataArray,
    lambda x: ((x.data,), {"dims": x.dims, "coords": x.coords}),
    lambda kwds, args: xr.DataArray(*args, **kwds)
)

da = xr.DataArray(
    data=jnp.array([2.0,3.0]),
    dims=("var"),
    coords={"var": ["A","B"]},
)
print(da)
# <xarray.DataArray (var: 2)>
# array([2., 3.], dtype=float32)
# Coordinates:
#   * var      (var) <U1 'A' 'B'

data, tree = tree_util.tree_flatten(da)
print(data)
# [array([2., 3.], dtype=float32)]

da_reconstructed = tree_util.tree_unflatten(tree, data)
print(da_reconstructed)
# <xarray.DataArray (var: 2)>
# array([2., 3.], dtype=float32)
# Coordinates:
#   * var      (var) <U1 'A' 'B'
```

I don't think there's much of a possibility that this will work as intended in any but the simplest of cases: for example, JAX transformations are restricted to functional, non-side-effecting code, and JAX arrays are immutable. xarray's operations in general violate both these constraints.

Another issue: you'd have to be careful to define your flatten and unflatten functions in a way that will ensure that all data and metadata is properly serialized, and if you're hoping to use this within any JAX function, be aware that you might run into issues with xarray's validation of inputs; see [Custom PyTrees and Initialization](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytrees.html#custom-pytrees-and-initialization) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. My implementation of the pytree is essentially the same. I wasn't so concerned about the un/flattening parts as I can control what attributes of xarray I use. The issue is that xarray functionality doesn't handle `DeviceArray`. For example:
`da.loc['A'] = 4.0` returns a `ValueError` with `Assignment destination is a view.  Do you want to .copy() array first?` _be aware that you might run into issues with xarray's validation of inputs_ – this is the key issue.

Comment: I tried `jnp.asarray(da.data).view(dtype='float32',type=jnp.DeviceArray)` and it returned `NotImplementedError` with `type argument of array.view()`... interesting. It seems you can't make a `DeviceArray` view of a `ndarray` view of a `DeviceArray`.

Comment: I think my answer covers that: you're trying to do an in-place modification of an immutable data buffer – it's not going to work.

Comment: Essentially it's not possible. The hope of intervening when xarray typecast the `DeviceArray`, which can be done in the unflatten call rather than the constructor call, is inhibited by xarray preventing direct access to it's state.